# Быстрая смена ip у домена

Tags: ip, dns

Нужно протестировать проект на другом сервере (посмотреть увеличиться ли производительность).

Идея очень простая - перенести все данные на тестовый сервер, и ночью сменить айпи домена на тестовsq сервер.

Вопрос: как максимально ускорить смену айпи у домена, кроме уменьшения TTL?

Comment: Так "A" записи, как и прочие, закешированы на куче серверов. Параметр TTL для того и предназначен. Вроде бы, ответ - никак.

Comment: Переведите ns на cloudflare. Изменение значений записей на клауде проталкивается за 5 минут.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Если даже cloude у себя изменит записи за 5 минут, это глобально в интернете ничего не изменит. Если какие либо DNS уже закешировали записи, они все равно не будут посылать повторных запросов на cloude  пока не истечет TTL записей. И на собственных DNS серверах у меня все изменения вообще проходят за секунду, целых 5 минут ждать не надо. Правда это разумеется так же глобально ничего не меняет

Comment: Что бы просто протестировать самому, до перевода клиентов, можно прописать домен у себя на компе в файле hosts и тогда информация из DNS лично для вас значения вообще не будет иметь

Comment: @Mike Вот как раз ничего подобного. Если бы не было опыта, я бы не писал. Меняешь А на nic.ru - и ждёшь 20 часов. Меняешь A на cloud - и максимум через 5 минут можешь работать с другим IP.

Comment: @KAGGDesign На cloude какой ttl по умолчанию в зоне ? и какой dns сервер используется на компе с которого проверяете ?

Comment: @Maki По умолчанию - Automatic. Возможные значения - от 2 минут до до 24 часов.

Comment: @Milke вот саппорт и пишет, что Automatic - это как раз 5 минут https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168866-What-does-the-Automatic-TTL-value-mean-

Comment: @KAGGDesign Тогда к чему вообще ваш комментарий про конкретного хостера DNS, если TTL можно самому хоть 1 секунду задать в зоне. И сделать это можно как на собственных DNS серверах так и на многих других. Посмотрите на том же nic.ru, может там TTL то же можно поменять. И вообще автор спрашивал можно ли без изменения TTL, а вы предлагаете конкретного хостера который делает через тот самый TTL

Comment: @Mike А к чему ваш комментарий "Если даже cloude у себя изменит записи за 5 минут, это глобально в интернете ничего не изменит."?

Comment: @KAGGDesign К тому, что я посчитал по тексту вашего комментария что вы говорите, что дело не в TTL, а как быстро хостер меняет записи _у себя_. Поэтому и написал, потому что скорость изменения записей у самого хостера к делу отношения обычно не имеет

Comment: поддомен сделай типа www1 и с главного сайта редиректни на новый сервер с этим поддоменом

Comment: проксировать можно, прокси много нагрузки не дает